# Nested JLayeredPane not rendering properly

Tags: java, jlayeredpane

I'm defining my own JLayeredPane derived class:

```
public class Decoration extends JLayeredPane {

    private int x, y;
    private boolean hiDef;
    private boolean[] region;

    public Decoration(boolean h, int x1, int y1){
        super();

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(128, 128));
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        hiDef = h;

        region = selectRegions();

        JLabel labelN = new JLabel();
        labelN.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("./resources/lgTree2.png"));
        this.add(labelN, new Integer(1));

        this.setOpaque(false)
    }
}
```

I then try to place this inside another JLayeredPane:

```
 JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
 panelMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 getContentPane().add(panelMain);
 JLayeredPane gameGrid = new JLayeredPane();
 gameGrid.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
 panelMain.add(gameGrid);
 Decoration decor = new Decoration(hiDef, j, k);
 gameGrid.add(decor, c, 9);
```

Unfortunately nothing is drawn on the screen. It works fine when I add a JLabel directly instead of the JLayeredPane. Is this because there's something different between nesting a JLayeredPane inside another one, and placing a JLabel inside the top level JLayeredPane vs the lower-level one?

Comment: Normally, JLayeredPane doesn't have a layout manager, so you become responsible for ensuring the size and position of the components. You try using a layout manager of your choice, all using setBounds of the child components

Comment: @MadProgrammer that fixed it, can you post it as  an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `JLayeredPane` doesn't have a layout manager, so you become responsible for ensuring the size and position of the components.

You try using a layout manager of your choice, or using `setBounds` of the child components